# How to go Back to Main View Controller form PhotoLibrary IOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, photolibrary

Hi I'm Uploading image form my device to server in the the photo library if user click the cancel button it has to go back to the main view controller but its going to the image pick view please tell to how to go back to main view controller from the photo library I'm using the story board.

```
    - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{

           [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
        }
```

The above i have used its not working please tell how to make it done.

Thanks

Comment: Make sure delegate is assigned to  UIImagePickerController.

Comment: put code of present your UIImagePickerController

Comment: @iPatel please read my question i want to go back to my mainview controller not to image pick view please give some solutions

Comment: I know that what are you saying.. for go to mainview controller is depends upon, how you gone on UIImagePickerController.. such like using presentViewController or pushViewController ??

Comment: no pls tell me how to do it

Answer (score 1):

you should use picker instead of self, When you photo library appears , its present modelViewController is called and when cancel ,dismissViewController is called as you have shown above. Now if you wan't to move to some other screen you have to use

```
   [self.navigationController popToViewController:urviewcontroller animated:YES ];
```

This method should be called after you have dismissed the modelViewController of photo library

Comment: pls tell me in the popview controller code what is uvir= controlleranimated and tell where i have to put this code.

Comment: my bad, it simply works like this. When you call
[self presentViewController:myPicker animated:YES completion:NULL]; 
 and when you are done with either selecting photo from library or cancel you call method 
 [myPicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Now this above code will show you library and also remove that library once  you are done with your selection or cancel.

After that if you wan't to move to any viewController use method
[self.navigationController popToViewController:yourVC animated:YES ];
yourVC is view controller on you want to move to/

Comment: i have committed the [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]; and i have used ur code its throwing error like Application tried to present modally an active controller

Comment: you haven't mentioned how you are selcting images from library? , can you write the code for that as well so that we can take a clear look?

Comment: i have tired using that in popview controller if ihave give the my view controller its showing error unexpected interface name 'myviewcontroller: expected expression

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49787/discussion-between-user3349668-and-rana)

Comment: sorry not able get u which selection code ur asking

Answer (score 0):

It should be `[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];`

Comment: @user3349668 imagePickerControllerDidCancel put breakpoint at this method and check its called on not?

Comment: @Sunnyshah the method is called its working only thing is the that i have used that code again its going to the image pick pleas tell me how to make it

Comment: Goingagain to image pick?  You are already there on it.  Right?

Comment: @user3349668 then aboove code is perfect. you should show your image picking code

Comment: @Sunnyshah please read my question i asked to how to go back to my mainviewcontroller from the photo library..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `presentModalViewController:` to present the UIImagePicker then use the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` to dismiss the presented view.

Comment: once the user press the cancel button i want to dismiss the photo library and its should go to my first view controller not to the image picker